# How should we handle popular canonicals that ask two separate questions?

Tags: discussion, canonical, needs-more-focus

Every now and then I find a popular question that asks two (mostly) unrelated questions at the same time. Basically like *"How do I do X? Also, how do I do Y?"*. Example: [User input and command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/user-input-and-command-line-arguments) asks how to read interactive input, *and* how to process command line arguments.

These kinds of questions are not only bad questions, but also bad duplicate targets. The answers are needlessly lengthy because they have to cover 2 separate topics. I would much rather have two separate canonicals for X and Y.

So, what should I do about broad canonical questions like this?

Things I've considered doing:

- Closing it as a duplicate of a "How do I do X?" question and a "How do I do Y?" question
- Pretending it doesn't exist

Comment: That doesn't look like two separate questions to me. It looks like a question asking how to make a single script both accept user input during runtime *and* accept command line args. If the answer is that you do not need to do anything special to have both features in the same script, then an answer would state so, preferably in addition to a sample containing examples of both simultaneously (be it using other resources or canonicals as a reference or using original content). Neither of the two duplicates of each part of the question would address this joint aspect of this particular question.

Comment: ... or at least, I wouldn't expect an answer to either X or Y to address the joint aspect since presumably that would be outside the scope of each individual question.

Comment: @BoltClock Hmm, well, none of the answerers seem to have interpreted the question that way though. Most answers just answer the X and the Y separately. (In fact, quite a few of them only answer the X.) So I'd say for all intents and purposes the question *is* asking two separate questions.

Comment: I see. That's just weird. Worse still the asker accepted one of them. In that case I think it would be acceptable to close it as a duplicate of both X and Y.

Comment: @BoltClock *"That doesn't look like two separate questions... If the answer is that you do not need to do anything special to have both features in the same script, then an answer would state so"* - But there's no reason to *expect* to have to do anything special in this case to let the features coexist. I'm skeptical of the line of argument in your first comment here since it seems to me like it would effectively legitimise bolting together any two vaguely-related how-to questions into a combined question, and that's almost always an unhelpful thing to do that we should want to discourage.

Comment: Somewhat similar: a [previous Meta question of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298912/1709587) where the mods helped split up another popular two-questions-in-one Python question. This one looks more difficult to unpick, though, since the answers are roughly evenly split between addressing the "accept user input" question and the "command line arguments" question, so just outright purging one of the two questions from the OP and all the answers is less viable in this case. :/

Comment: You mean like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52193919/1026459), which not only asks how to use a common feature, but also *when* to use it. Should that not also be removed? Or, perhaps asked as "how to" *and* "when to"? Or perhaps closed as a duplicate of either or both? There is an extreme hypocrisy here. My point is this: the type of behavior of finding nuance to get rid of questions which should be here is beginning to weigh far too heavily on this site. We need to actively reconsider the ways in which we are using the closure tool to remove content which has value.

Comment: @TravisJ Should it be removed? Maybe. I know it's a very broad question, but there's an important difference: I don't think it's possible to answer the "when" and the "how" separately. If you ask those questions individually, they both become worthless. To put it differently, it's not asking two *separate* questions. It's asking two very closely related questions. But to address your main point: If you feel so strongly about the SO community's tendency to close questions you find useful, please post an answer explaining why you think these kinds of questions shouldn't be closed (or removed).

Comment: @TravisJ Not a fair comparison. The answers to "how to" and "when to" are related to each other. The answers to the two questions in *this* case are completely independent. If we had the tooling, we could split this question into two manually-crafted subquestions, and then each answer could either be migrated to one or the other or literally split into two answers by simply cutting it in two at a paragraph break. The two questions are so unrelated that the answers that address both just do so in two different sections that don't relate to each other at all.

Comment: @MarkAmery - Meh, a misguided belief, but I at least understand where you get it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions asking multiple questions (more precisely, violating the one-concern-per-question principle) are close-worthy as too broad:

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough
>   detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct
>   questions at once.** See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this
>   question.

Once a question is closed, it can be deleted regardless of the votes (but highly upvoted questions require much more deletion votes). I've actually seen old, closed, highly-upvoted questions in the deletion queue many times.

This may sound harsh, but fixing them otherwise does not fit into the SO model as it is: [it's considered illegal to edit a question in any way that invalidates existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311297/inadvertently-invalidating-answers-with-a-modest-question-edit/311433#311433) (all the more illegal if the question and/or the answers have already accumulated votes because this invalidates those votes, too -- and there's no way to forcibly roll them back or solicit reconsideration of them from the voters or something).

If the problem is popular enough, there's either other questions covering it already, or one will eventually be asked and answered in hopefully a better way.

Comment: So you would recommend deleting the question? Or just close it as too broad and leave it there? If it's the latter, surely closing the question as duplicate would be better (so that visitors from google can find an answer to the question)?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes, I recommend closing, then deleting (or rather, this is the way that the system currently supports). While I've seen questions closed as multiple duplicates, I don't know how this can be done, and in any case, it's too fragile, you aren't going to succeed in coercing reviewers to do such a complicated combined action. Getting it closed as anything at all is hard enough as it is.

Comment: Closing it as dupe is actually easier because that can be done single-handedly by a gold badge holder. (And gold badge holders can close as dupe of 2 or more questions.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey then you need to somehow reach and involve some gold badge holder -- the system doesn't provide any workflow for this. I still wouldn't recommend leaving a close-worthy question there. It being deleted is not a big deal -- if there are others, Google will find them, no need to go an extra mile here.

Comment: They were not distinct questions though, they were facets. The question was easily answered within the allotted space for an answer. The precedence of deleting popular canonicals because of a vague interpretation of too broad, or to put it in relative terms, a too broad interpretation of too broad, is dangerous.

Comment: @TravisJ that's why I added the clarification note: _"more precisely, violating the one-concern-per-question principle"_ "Concern" is less prone to be taken literally than "question". (Of course, what constitues a concern is still up to community consensus for interpretation, but this is as precise as we can get.)

Comment: There is the common guideline of one question per question, because list questions are bad. However, there is not a "one-concern-per-question principle". Again, interpreting the suggestions as law, literally calling the practice of not abiding by vaguely defined suggestions as "illegal", leads to a situation where anything can be considered for closure. This is not a good direction for the site. It has been going on for far too long, and people have started to take this type of interpretation way too far. Excessively closing and removing content is bad for the site.

Comment: @TravisJ Whether the questions such as the discussed ones are "good" for the site is a matter of opinion. Which "direction" the site takes is up to which standpoint has more support in the community and/or the team. Write an answer or  some separate post defending your standpoint and let's see how much support it gets.

Comment: I have written answers regarding this, but I am more concerned with the outlook that you provide here. It is damaging. There are now years of data, and as this has been the norm, there is no longer an opinion of the direction the site is going. There is simple factual data that there is a problem with closing these types of questions. The only opinions left at this point are which solution should be used.

Comment: @TravisJ No-one single-handedly decides "which solution should be used" in each and every case, it rather "arises naturally" from various contributing sources: discussions, consensus by distributing parts of a decision between members, team blog posts. Meta posts offer guidance and prior community feedback for readers seeking advice and can thusly sway these collective decisions as well.

Comment: @TravisJ This post is a proposed solution to a specific problem. Write another proposed solution and let the community feedback show which one they currently consider a better one and why -- and let community members decide whose justifications they consider stronger to be used in their future decisions.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this solution. Just write two separated questions and delete the one asking two things at the same time. Is very straightforward.

Comment: @TravisJ they are **not** "facets". The way that one reads user input from standard input (more or less equivalent: prompt the user to type something, and read what was typed) has **nothing to do with** how to make use of the command-line arguments (which **isn't even "reading"**, in that the command line has already been tokenized by the shell and supplied as a list - "reading" implies interpreting either a single string or a single sequence of raw bytes). I also discovered that multiple previous edits mis-represented the original question. It took considerable effort just now to fix that.

Comment: "The question was easily answered within the allotted space for an answer." Sure, by *writing two answers for different questions consecutively within the same Answer*. That's blatantly not how the site is supposed to work.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Way to butcher a question from 2008. The site was different then, and these *are* facets of the same user input issue. How do I capture user input and make use of it is the essence of this question. Honestly though, if you look at what you are really describing, you would rather the site work as a single line of code answer for single question raised. The wording of too broad is problematic, as is pretty much understood by now, and these types of situations highlight why: pedantically interpreting rules is terrible for the site. This was a slowpitch question, don't overthink it.

Comment: There are many questions from 2008 that should be butchered; this is one of them. There is nothing pedantic about the rules interpretation here; it's clear as day, and the rule serves a clear and vital purpose. Command line parameters **are not the same kind of thing as** interactive input. Someone who wants to ask explicitly about both has two questions. Someone who is only trying to figure out ways to provide input to a program has done neither the necessary [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) nor the design work - we aren't a discussion forum. The question is NMF.

Comment: "Honestly though, if you look at what you are really describing, you would rather the site work as a single line of code answer for single question raised." No, not even remotely. I have recently written several answers that were multiple screens long, for questions that I thought were perfectly well focused - because the subject matter merited such a treatment. We don't have a "Too Broad" close rule any more; it is called "Needs More Focus", and it is definitely not applied "pedantically" *enough*.

Comment: Ultimately, the purpose of this exercise is to make questions *searchable*. Someone who wants to know about both things, and doesn't know that both things exist, cannot do a search at all, due to being too confused. Someone who wants to know about one, **should see specific answers** for that one. From the [relevant FAQ](/questions/417476): "Such posts don't create proper references for people with similar problems, making it difficult for others to find answers. Also, as with too broad questions, answers to such questions tend to be longer and harder to read or write."

Answer (score 4):

I feel that the question (and main answer) miss the point slightly.

While this is not necessarily always true, a question that asks two seemingly independent things at the same time, under the assumption that they are related, is also largely a question on *whether* or *how* they are related, and an answer is therefore not necessarily sought as two independent answers, but as one answer that also attempts to address the link between them. A *good* answer in this case may be to point out that these are in fact two independent questions, and that there is no actual link, or explain to what extent their common context differentiates their otherwise independent use.

This is especially the case in 'popular' questions, because it means people land on this question having been under the same impression of a contextual link. Closing it as a duplicate of other questions that do not address this link (or why the assumption of such a link is a false assumption) does a disservice to these users.

I often see this attitude on SO, where more knowledgeable users treat questions under the assumption that the person asking should have known better, and thus should not be wasting people's time, but in fact the point of the question is that they don't know better in the first place, and are here to gain some insight from the 'experts'. This is potentially one such example, the assumption being "you should have clearly known that the contextual link is misleading and in fact the two questions are independent problems".

With regard to the explicit example given, the assumption from more knowledgeable users is that the asker *knows* the two are independent problems, but for all we know, the user does not, and are therefore absolutely correct to ask it in this manner. If there is a number of solutions and one of them treats both interactive and command input via a common underlying interface, then *this* answer would have been the one most relevant to their problem. And if there *isn't* a common interface, then *this* fact is relevant to the question, and then a good answer points this out.

Comment: You may have a point, but it's a problem if the question doesn't **clearly** ask how the two things are related. If you look at the question I used as an example, you'll see that there isn't a single answer that addresses the link between the two questions. Some answers answer the X and the Y individually, some answer only the X, and others answer only the Y. If the OP's intention was to ask about the link between X and Y, they have failed miserably. We now have a garbage dump of bad and incomplete answers to show for it. What do you suggest we should do about that? Nothing?

Comment: @Aran-Fey of course not. Nothing would be the other extreme. But it's important enough to point out. There are probably more organic ways to tackle such questions (downvoting, explaining, asking user to rephrase etc). I feel arbitrarily policing and closing questions as a matter of 'due process' with little consideration of context nuance will surely cause more harm and frustration than a benefit. Secondly, such questions are also an opportunity to flag topics that mistakenly appear together, and provide good quality answers that make that point; closing them down will only make them reappear.

Comment: The linked question is asking about two clearly unrelated things: command line arguments and user input. It doesn't matter whether the asker knows that or not.

Comment: @jpmc26 Why not? Is it because "their kind" don't belong here anyway, and this site is "for professionals"? (\end{trolling}). While in an ideal world it would be nice if people asking questions here were proficient enough to know the answers to begin with, so that they could ask better questions (oxymoron aside), in practice the fact there's over 1.5k votes on that page suggests that maybe it _does_ matter that people don't realise they are "clearly" unrelated, and that maybe the SO population isn't homogeneous and only accessible to "professionals", thus to many this question provided value.

Comment: Because if you know the terms at all, you know you're dealing with two separate concepts. Someone who confuses them wouldn't know there are separate terms to begin with for Googling. There is therefore no need to combine them. Should we have combined questions for every possible combination of topics? Why don't we have a question about floating point imprecision and integer overflow in the same question? They both result from addition, right?

Comment: @jpmc26 Absolutely not. I never said we should either. The point I'm making is it's bound to happen for various reasons (good or bad) _anyway_, and neither 'force closing' or 'ignoring them altogether' addresses the underlying issue, but likely propagates it even further.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Closure is not the same as deletion. If the point is to have a signpost to get people to look elsewhere, a closed question will fulfill that purpose just fine. (Duplicate closure is *explicitly* intended to do so.) There's already comments on the question doing that. There is no point in duplicating that content in an answer just in case someone might be extraordinarily confused.

Comment: @jpmc26 I appreciate what you're saying, but this is now going round in circles. It's only a duplicate if the link isn't significant. And it's only insignificant if treated as a duplicate. If closed, it disables better answers from appearing organically that disambiguate the role of the link specifically, and redirect towards the more canonical answers. Worse, you invite people to redirect discussion of said link in the context of the 'duplicate' where the link is now contextual noise. I don't know what the right answer is, but it seems to me it's more complicated than 'closing vs ignoring'

Comment: There is *zero* overlap between reading input and passing command line arguments. They are completely different things. Your entire argument rests on the vague assumption that there is some useful commentary to be made about the two in combination. If there's some specific thing to be said about them together, *that* question needs to be asked *specifically*. *This* question, which doesn't even begin to identify any kind of connection between the two, and any like it should be closed.

Comment: The **common** case, IMX, is that the person asking thinks the question is "how do I do Z?", but *people who know how to do Z* recognize that Z consists of clear, distinct steps X and Y, both of which are well-covered by canonicals. However, that doesn't seem to apply to the example discussed here.